# css font family preference changing

Tags: css

I am applying font to the text using :

```
font: bold 1.416666666666667em Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
```

so the meaning is Helvetica is the first preferred font, if that is not there then go for Arial but it not happening, it is directly taking arial font.

in case if i remove the arial from font property it apply the Helvetica..

```
font: bold 1.416666666666667em Helvetica,sans-serif;
```

so, how can i solve this issue, when helvetica availability i need only helvetica, else let it go for arial but not as first choice.

any good way to achieve this?

Comment: Just to confirm, your issue is that you've got the font rule with `Helvetica` at the front but you're still seeing `Arial` right?

Comment: @AshwinSingh where would you like to place them?

Comment: @ Marty Wallace, yes that's my issue.

Comment: So, maybe you don't have Helvetica font in your system?

Comment: Please provide more information. The first rule should do exactly what you describe. Is it the exact code you have? How did you infer that Arial and not Helvetica is used? (The fonts look rather similar.) What happens if you declare `sans-serif` only? I could explain the phenomenon if Helvetica (or a lookalike) exists in the system but under a different name and the browser uses it as the generic sans-serif font.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
.classname {font-family: bold 1.416666666666667em 'Helvetica' ,Arial, sans-serif;}
```

If that fails, maybe this...

```
.classname {font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1.416666666666667em; font-weight: bold;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) Select the font you like.

Add the Link href code between the `<head></head>` Tags

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And add the Font-family part to you're style.css file at BODY.

```
body {
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
font-size:1.5em;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

[The other option is to read this tutorial about Using Fonts](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/webdesignfonts/a/aa051903a.htm)

Comment: `font` is not a selector here - w3schools doesn't approve this syntax. Anyways, w3schools is... not always exactly accurate: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: `bold 1.5em ...` was definitely not meant to be a font family. I don't know of any font named `1.5em`.

Comment: Haha sorry, Still tired haha :). 
W3schools is not always providing the exact right HTML, but it is a good website to find resources for starting Webdesigners/Scripters

Comment: I don't know of a font named `"Helvetica,sans-serif"`. Keep trying :-)